# Angular 5 template can't call static method

Tags: static-methods, angular5

In my component I have a simple static method defined:

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    static onSelectAllPressed(element: AudioElement): void {
    }
```

and then in my template html file I try to link that to a button click:

```
<button mat-button (click)="AppComponent.onSelectAllPressed(element)">Select All</button>
```

It builds (ng build --prod) without issue, but when I click on the button I'm getting an error in the console saying:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'onSelectAllPressed' of undefined

I can't understand why this is failing.  Are we simply not allowed to access static methods?

Comment: That would translate to `AppComponent.AppComponent.onSelectAllPressed(element)`. Try just `(click)="onSelectAllPressed(element)"`

Comment: That results in `ERROR TypeError: t.component.onSelectAllPressed is not a function`

Comment: See this answer. You can't call static methods from a view, you need to expose that method via the component. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41857120/1411687

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call static function from angular2 template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41857047/call-static-function-from-angular2-template)

Comment: Strange they don't support static functions.  I'll just leave it non-static then.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need static method here, you can use an anonymous function

```
onSelectAllPressed = (element: AudioElement) => element.whatYouNeed;
```

And it is easy to call in a template

```
<button mat-button
    (click)="onSelectAllPressed(element)">
Select All</button>
```

Comment: better do it like supposed by @alex wiese pointing to günter's proposal of exposing a static method as a member https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41857047/call-static-function-from-angular2-template/41857120#41857120