# html binding of a static property

Tags: angular, typescript, components, angular2-template

I have a module made of a component and a template. 
In the component I have a static function (I need it to be static because I'm making a library) and so I also have a static property which will contain a string of html.

I'm trying to bind this property to my template using [innerhtml].

Component.ts:

export class AppSqvComponent {

```
static sqv: string;


static myFunc(): void {

        this.sqv = myHtmlString;

}
```

Template.html:

The template can not recognize "sqv", it says the variable is unresolved.

Comment: I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41857120/2814332) solves your problem.

Comment: Problem solved:
In my ts.config.json I had to set "module": "esnext", and "target": "es2015". Before I was using es5.
I don't fully understand, but I think it was a problem during compilation, maybe I was using some old syntax not compatible with my settings in the config... 

With this I could implement my function and properties without using the static keyword, being then able to do the html binding in the classic way.
Thank you for your help anyway!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your "sqv" property is static (belongs to a class ). For this reason you cannot use it together with "this" ... "this" indicates that it belongs to an instance already created and not to a class ...

```
export class AppSqvComponent {
    static sqv: string;
    static myFunc(): void {
            this.sqv = myHtmlString; //===> wrong
    }
```

You must use it like this:

```
export class AppSqvComponent {
    static sqv: string;
    static myFunc(): void {
            AppSqvComponent.sqv = myHtmlString; //===> Ok
    }
```