# installed npm package but get "is not a function" error in browser

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using **Ionic 4** and trying to use this lib: https://date-fns.org to get a date string like `2019-11-01 07:23:22` to be displayed in human readable way.

So I've installed the lib with:

```
npm install date-fns --save
```

Then in `mypage.ts` file

```
import { format, formatDistance, parseISO } from 'date-fns';
```

And then in `mypage.html` file

```
<div class="date">{{ formatDistance(parseISO(h.created_at)) }}</div>
```

So I'm getting this error in browser console:

```
ERROR TypeError: _co.parseISO is not a function
```

It says the function doesn't exists, but it's in the docs: https://date-fns.org/v2.6.0/docs/parseISO

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only instance members of the components class can be called from the view.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41857120/7562674

In Ts File:-

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { format, formatDistance, parseISO } from 'date-fns';

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

formatDistance=formatDistance;
parseISO=parseISO;  
date=  "2018-10-01";
d=new Date(2015, 0, 1)
constructor(){
  console.log(formatDistance(parseISO("2018-10-01"), new Date(2015, 0, 
  1)))
  }
```

In template:-

```
  <p>{{formatDistance(parseISO(date),d)}}</p>
```

I checked this is working.

Declare as variable and assign it instead of injecting in constructor argument. Since it is a function not a class that why showing error not as type when used in constructor.

Comment: it causes this error: `error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'formatDistance' as a type`

Comment: updated the answer. Have you tried as instance variable instead of injecting in constructor.

Answer (score 1):

In TS file:

```
import { format, formatDistance, parseISO } from 'date-fns';

constructor(public formatDistance: formatDistance) {
}
```

This is HTML

```
<div class="date">{{ formatDistance(parseISO(h.created_at)) }}</div>
```

Comment: it causes this error: `error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'formatDistance' as a type`