# Static functions in Angular-template

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In our project we use the linting-config from [AirBnB](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-airbnb). [The is a rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/class-methods-use-this#enforce-that-class-methods-utilize-this-class-methods-use-this), that says class methods must use `this` or be declared as static. In theory this rule makes a lot of sense to me, but in the angular context seems to cause some problems. Imagine a component like this ([Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-static-in-template?file=src/app/app.component.ts)):

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<p>{{doSomething("hello stack overflow")}}'
})
export class AppComponent  {
  doSomething(string: string): string {
    return string.toLocaleUpperCase();
  }
}
```

Now, the linter would complain about `doSomething` not using this. Wen can now make the function static to satisfy it - but than we would not be able to use the function in the template.

One conclusion would be, that `doSomething` should not be part of AppComponent but another service for example. But than we would have to wrap the static function in non-static one again. In the end the wrapping function is not much smaller than the original one, so the whole outsourcing to service thing seems kind of pointless. Especially since we speak of functions which are *explicitly* only useful for the template of the component. It seems to be problematic especially with tracking function for `trackBy` of `ngForOf` - they tend to not use a `this` keyword by nature and are only used in template, so they can not be static.

- See [Call static function from angular2 template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41857047/call-static-function-from-angular2-template)

So is there a meaningful pattern how to handle functions which are used in templates together with this rule or is it just not not a useful rule for angular?

Comment: I would say that you can use Angular pipes (https://angular.io/guide/pipes) for those template data transformation functions. In fact you can use them in the trackBy too (https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3579-using-pure-pipes-to-generate-ngfor-trackby-identity-functions-in-angular-7-2-7.htm). But then the linter would complain about the pipes.. So as pipes are an important part of Angular I would say that maybe the rule it´s not a good match for Angular (unless you can exclude pipes from it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a satisfying solution myself:

I convert the those function - small, UI-related, used (only) in template, not using the scope (`this`) as fields, holding arrow functions.

```
  doSomething = (string: string): string => string.toLocaleUpperCase();
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also define in a .ts externals functions like:

```
export function myFunction(name){
   return "Hello "+name;
}
```

You only need in one component

```
import {myFunction} from './myfile.ts'
```

Then you can use in .ts

```
   myFunction("Me");
```

If you want to use in the html you need declare in your .ts

```
  myFunctionI=myFunction;
```

And use

```
  {{myFunctionI('me')}}
```

Other option: your .ts like

```
export function Util() {
    return new UtilClass()
}
class UtilClass {
   greet(name){
       return "Hello "+name;
   }
}
```

And you can

```
import {Util} from './myfile-util.ts' 

console.log(Util.greet("me"))
```

Comment: But for using them in the template (the `html`-part of the component), I would have to wrap them in some member-functions of the component.

Comment: @Paflow, in html all the "variables" are refered to a "this". e.g. you can **not** use directlty in a .html `{{Math.round(3.2)}}`. But you can declare in your component `IMath=Math` and then you use `{{IMath.round(3.2)}}` -I like add an "I" before the "variable", but it's only a personal option-. Equal another "function" or class you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

For your case, I think a pipe is better.